# Absolute Convergence of Difference Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty R_ky_k < \infty
\quad\forall y\in l_\infty 
~~\text{(that is such that $\left|y_k\right|<\infty$ $\forall k$)}
$$
then show that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left|R_k\right| < \infty
$$
Here we also know that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty R_k < \infty
$$
We can think of $R_k$ sequences of any terms. I can not remember any test works on it and can not proceed to find absolute convergence.

A hint or any answer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: consider $y_k = {\rm sign}(R_k)$...

### Edit (full solution)

The sequence
$$
  y_k = {\rm sign}(R_k) =
  \begin{cases}
    +1 & \text{if } R_k > 0 \\
    0 & \text{if } R_k = 0 \\
    -1 & \text{if } R_k < 0
  \end{cases}
$$
belongs to $l_\infty$, so by hypothesis $\sum_k R_ky_k < \infty$.
Notice that $R_ky_k = |R_k|$, which concludes the proof.

Comment: I am sorry but I still do not get the answer. Could you please elaborate the hint? How does your hint help me solve absolute convergence part?

Comment: Thanks I got the answer:)))